# Как записать в файл, который хранится в ресурсах?

Tags: java, io, resources

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть текстовый файл, где хранятся очки игры, предполагал, что файл будет хранится в ресурсах, с чтением файла я разобрался, но мне надо в него и записывать, новый рекорд например. Как это сделать? Или подскажите как лучше поступить в данной ситуации.

Comment: Вносить изменения в файлы ресурсов (я имею ввиду те, что лежат в самом jar'нике) плохая идея. Тут лучше использовать внешнее хранилище. Файлик, системный реестр или ещё что-то. Наиболее частый вариант, это создание в каталоге данных пользователя директории приложения, куда складываются данные и настройки приложения. Обычно имена таких директорий начинаются с точки. Пошло это правило из Linux, где такие директории по умолчанию скрыты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Путь тот же самый что и при считывании.
Пример записи:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        String fileName = "someFile.txt";
        ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
        Path path = Paths.get(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getPath());
        writeFile(path, "test data");
    }

    private static void writeFile(Path path, String data) throws IOException {
        Files.write(path, data.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    }
}
```

Опции записи задаются с помощью StandardOpenOption констант путем перечисления (например создать новый файл, или дописать в конец файла)
Самый простой способ в Вашем случае: при старте программы считывать данные и преобразовывать в какой-нибудь класс, а затем при завершении работы перезаписывать файлик данными из этого класса.